# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' ( WITH PHP ONLY )

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an input that I want to get the value of in "Arabic"
and I did this code

```
token = soup.find('input', {'name':'EmpName'})['value']
print(token)
```

and it works in the terminal ( cmd )

 but the real problem that whenever I try to print the output with php it keeps giving me this error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character 
maps to
```

I used this PHP code to print the output and it works with anything else

```
<?php echo exec('python q.py 2>&1'); ?>
```

I tried to add

```
print(token.encode('cp1252'))
print(token.encode('utf-8'))
```

didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding ignore errors and encoding it to utf-8 and then decoding it to cp1252 cuz I'm on windows

```
vo = (token.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
print (vo.decode('cp1252', errors='ignore'))
```